# How to Download File from URl in WP8 in External storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have one download URl,
How to download file from this url in c# Code . wp8 . 
and This file may be store in external storage not be use isolated storage because file is so large Please Help

Comment: Be aware that not every - rather very few - have external storage, e.g. Lumia 800, 920, HTX 8X and so on. Perhaps you should review your workflow to avoid the hideous big file :)
Besides that, much customers do not like apps that use high bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpClient` for downloading files, see sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664).
Also, you must use `IsolatedStorage` since you don't have external storage available to you. Also, consider using `Windows.Storage` instead of `IsolatedStorage`.

Comment: Hello sir , i dont want to use isolatedstorage requirement is file save in Phone or sd-card . isolatedstorage is limited

Comment: You *cannot* save on phone or SD card, that is not possible. You can only *read* data from SD card http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573%28v=vs.105%29.aspx.

Comment: BUt when i use HYperLinkButton and set the NavigateUri="http//www.web.com/download.pdf" then is auto start a downloading in web browser and file auto save in external storage . the same think i want to use in backend by C# . Please Help

Comment: That is different, you still cannot use it in your code.